# Ubuntu 19.04 as virtualbox guest on Win10 host, seamless mode not working correctly

Tags: gnome, virtualbox, virtualization, windows-10, 19.04

I am trying to run a Ubuntu 19.04 VM on Windows 10. I have the guest utils installed, and everything seems to be working, including being able to switch to seamless mode.

The problem is when I switch to seamless mode all I see is any windows I already have open. I loose the Gnome top bar, and dock on the left side. I really need to have the dock, and top bar, otherwise seamless mode becomes pretty useless for me.

Comment: you need  to take this up with virtualbox. this is how virtualbox behaves for everyone, not just you. that being said I tested on Kubuntu for shits and giggles, it turns out kubuntu gets to keep the taskbar. again take it up with virtualbox.

Comment: hmmm, interesting. I started looking more into this and did find that its pretty much how it works for Linux guests. However I didn't know about KDE working. Maybe ill try that instead.

Comment: not KDE as a host. KDE as a guest.